# How to parse (width)x(height) command-line argument into two arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

So my goal is to enter `80x40` and it enters it in `size` and return with the format `(80, 40)`.

But if I write `80xdf`, it will give an error message and use the default value,
then I also want it to give an error when you write one of the `arguments < 1`.

Also if it's formatted wrong, it should give out an error message.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('width', type=int, help='width of the world')
parser.add_argument('x', type=int, help='x')
parser.add_argument('height', type=int, help='height of the world')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.width and args.height < 1:
    print("Both width and height needs to have positive values above zero.")
    print("Using default world size: 80x40")
    size = tuple(80, 40)
elif args.format(args.width, args.x, args.height):
    size = tuple("{},{}".format(args.width, args.height))
else:
    print("World size should contain width and height, separated by ‘x’. Ex:'80x40'")
    print("Using default world size: 80x40")
    size = tuple(80, 40)
```

Error I face when I enter -ws 80x40 -g 0:

```
usage: main.py [-h] width x height
main.py: error: argument width: invalid int value: '80x40'
```

Comment: You have "width" and "height" as two separate arguments, but are passing them as a single string "80x40"; try passing them separately or parsing them accordingly.

Comment: You didn't make a single cli argument that takes number x number. You made 3 cli arguments that take 3 separate integers. So You can give `80 0 40` to it (the 0 is what you will save in `x`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true)

Comment: @dsillman2000 so if i want to enter 80x40, should i use split() first so that they become 3 separate strings?

Comment: @BoarGules How is that a duplicate? While it is indeed a valid problem with the code, it is not what the question is about. The code didn't even reach that part yet. The problem is with how the OP defined and passes the arguments. That link should be recommended, not a duplicate target...

Answer (score 2):

In your snippet, you didn't make a single cli argument that takes `NxM`. You made 3 cli arguments that take 3 separate (spaces!) integers.

So you can enter e.g. `80 0 40` and it will parse (with middle number being saved as `x`).

---

The easiest, out-of-the-box solution, is to require exactly 2 integers for size.

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('size', nargs=2)
args = parser.parse_args()

size = args.size
```

Or two positional arguments like you did... but without that x "argument" and without writing x when executing.

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('width')
parser.add_argument('height')
args = parser.parse_args()

size = args.width, args.height
```

### Both of those will require you to pass arguments as just `80 40`, no x, space is needed.

Afterwards, you can go with your ifs.
As BoarGules linked, you messed up how `and` works.

Your `if args.width and args.height < 1:` means `if args.width and (args.height < 1):` and any non-empty non-zero value is truthy.

It should be `if args.width<0 or args.height<0` - two conditions and you want either of them to be true, hence `or`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there any possible way for me to do it by entering 80x40, as the task is that the data should be entered as numberxnumber?

Comment: Get a string, split is manually using .split('x'). Check if result has exactly 2 parts and if both of those parse as ints

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you really want to pass the argument as `80x40` you can define a single argument with a custom [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type):

```py
import argparse

def parse_world_size_arg(arg: str) -> tuple:
    """ Parse width and height from command argument. """
    return tuple(map(int, arg.split('x')))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('size', type=parse_world_size_arg, help='widthxheight of the world')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.size)
```

And if the above code will be run as `python main.py 80x40` the output will be:

```
(80, 40)
```

---

Then you can add some input validation if necessary:

```py
def parse_world_size_arg(arg: str) -> tuple:
    """ Parse width and height from command argument. """
    try:
        return tuple(map(int, arg.split('x')))
    except ValueError:
        return tuple()

...
args = parser.parse_args()
size = (80, 40)
if len(args.size) != 2:
    print("World size should contain width and height, separated by ‘x’. Ex:'80x40'")
    print("Using default world size: 80x40")
elif any(dim < 1 for dim in args.size):
    print("Both width and height need to have positive values above zero.")
    print("Using default world size: 80x40")
else:
    size = args.size
```

Comment: unfortunately i still get :
usage: gol.py [-h] [-g GENERATIONS] [-s SEED] [-ws WORLDSIZE] [-f FILE]
gol.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 80x40

Comment: Because that's a completely different parser definition than what you gave in the question... Apparently you need `python main.py -ws 80x40`

Comment: @Snapy Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: no, but im going trying with "while try except" but im focused on other things atm :)